# Postman Chrome plugin - export history (Rest calls)

Tags: rest, client, postman

Howto export history (URL, method and headers) in plain text file

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Request/Response export is not supported in `Postman` as of version `3.1.2`. If you have a frequent need of this you can consider switching to [Paw](https://paw.pt/) (it's paid though).